# Dropdown city in checkout

Tags: magento-1.8, shipping

I use Magento 1.8 and I won't to add a dropdown selection in my city field in checkout.
Make shipping only in certain cities, if I already have a selection of those available can better manage shipments.

Comment: Have a look at the blog post http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/configuring-city-as-dropdown-option-in-checkout-billing-shipping-address/ this might be a good start

Comment: I try to use this, but when I refresh page I have an error in Mage.php: "PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Mage_Citydropdown_Helper_Data' not found in /home/ronchiat/public_html/prova/app/Mage.php on line 547"

Comment: In that case you are missing the helper definition from the config.xml, if you post what code you have maybe we can find the bug

Comment: I apologize, but I did not understand what should I do

Comment: For now simply update the question with all the custom code you wrote for this task.

Comment: I don't wrote any code, I just followed the directions of the blog

Comment: But I want to display city in admin page. and can edit and update for customer by admin. I want to display city dropdown filter by state/province

Answer (score 6):

So following the steps outlined in the blog from [MagePsycho](http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/configuring-city-as-dropdown-option-in-checkout-billing-shipping-address/) on this task.

**Create basic module**

Let's follow this blog and say that the module will have the name `MagePsycho_Citydropdown`. In this case we will need an extension xml file under the path `app/etc/modules` with the name `MagePsycho_Citydropdown.xml`. It will look like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MagePsycho_Citydropdown>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Core/>
                <Mage_Directory/>
            </depends>
        </MagePsycho_Citydropdown>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Since we need the directory module later on we should add the depends here and since we also extend a Mage_Core file we need that depends.

**Create module's config.xml**

Next the module will need a config.xml file to inform Magento what and how to work with the Module. So create the folder sctructure `app/code/local/MagePsycho/Citydropdown/etc`. The local part is defined in the `MagePsycho_Citydropdown.xml`. Then inside this folder create a `config.xml` file. This file should contain the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MagePsycho_Citydropdown>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </MagePsycho_Citydropdown>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <citydropdown>
                <class>MagePsycho_Citydropdown_Helper</class>
            </citydropdown>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

This simply tells Magento that when someone is looking for a helper with the code `Mage::helper('citydropdown')` that you should look for a class that starts like `MagePsycho_Citydropdown_Helper`

**Add helper class**

Now we can build our helper so we need to create the folder `Helper` under `app/code/local/MagePsycho/Citydropdown` and then create a file `Data.php` in the `Helper` folder. This file will contain the look up for cities.

```
<?php
/**
 * @category   MagePsycho
 * @package    MagePsycho_Citydropdown
 * @author     magepsycho@gmail.com
 * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */
class MagePsycho_Citydropdown_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function getUaeCities()
    {
        $helper = Mage::helper('directory');
        $cities = array(
            $helper->__('Abu Dhabi'),
            $helper->__('Ajman'),
            $helper->__('Al Ain'),
            $helper->__('Dubai'),
            $helper->__('Fujairah'),
            $helper->__('Ras al Khaimah'),
            $helper->__('Sharjah'),
            $helper->__('Umm al Quwain'),
        );
        return $cities;
    }

    public function getUaeCitiesAsDropdown($selectedCity = '')
    {
        $cities = $this->getUaeCities();
        $options = '';
        foreach($cities as $city){
            $isSelected = $selectedCity == $city ? ' selected="selected"' : null;
            $options .= '<option value="' . $city . '"' . $isSelected . '>' . $city . '</option>';
        }
        return $options;
    }
}
```

As noted in the blog itself you could create a couple of tables to populate the city information from the database. If you are working with a lot of city information then I would suggest this approach, but I will continue with using the blog's code.

> **Notes:** You can also populate the cities in db tables to make it more
>   dynamic. For example, you can create following tables similar to
>   regions:
>   + directory_country_city (city_id, country_id, code, default_name)
>   + directory_country_city_name (locale, city_id, name)

**Update front end display of address**

Now what this blog entry does is assume the following.

1. That you already have JQuery included in your Magento installation,
2. That you only want to make this change on the checkout pages,
3. That you already have a theme setup,

Neither of these are massive changes but can be achieved with a few searches on Google and so I will not cover that here. So moving on with the blog we will need to add to the billing and shipping address templates.

So take a copy of the base template and add it to your theme if your do not already have it. The templates you will need are:

1. `app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml`
2. `app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml`

Now are the top of the billing.phtml add the following code snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <?php
    $helper          = Mage::helper('citydropdown');
    $address         = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getBillingAddress();
    $defaultCity     = $address->getCity();
    $citiesOptions   = addslashes($helper->getUaeCitiesAsDropdown($defaultCity));
    ?>

    var billingCity = '<?php echo $defaultCity ; ?>';
    function billingSwitchCityField(){
        var selectVal = jQuery('#billing\\:country_id option:selected').val();
        if(selectVal == "AE"){
            jQuery("#billing\\:city")
            .replaceWith('<select id="billing:city" name="billing[city]" class="required-entry">' +
                  '<option value=""></option>' +
                  '<?php echo $citiesOptions; ?>' +
                '</select>');
        }else{
            jQuery("#billing\\:city")
            .replaceWith('<input type="text" class=" input-text required-entry absolute-advice " title="City" value="' + billingCity + '" id="billing:city" name="billing[city]" autocomplete="off">');
        }

    }
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        billingSwitchCityField();
        jQuery('#billing\\:country_id').change(function() {
            billingSwitchCityField();
        });
   })
</script>
```

And at the top of the shipping template add the following snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <?php
    $helper          = Mage::helper('citydropdown');
    $address         = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();
    $defaultCity     = $address->getCity();
    $citiesOptions   = addslashes($helper->getUaeCitiesAsDropdown($defaultCity));
    ?>




    var shippingCity = '<?php echo $defaultCity ; ?>';
    function shippingSwitchCityField(){
        var selectVal = jQuery('#shipping\\:country_id option:selected').val();
        if(selectVal == "AE"){
            jQuery("#shipping\\:city")
            .replaceWith('<select id="shipping:city" name="shipping[city]" class="required-entry">' +
                  '<option value=""></option>' +
                  '<?php echo $citiesOptions; ?>' +
                '</select>');
        }else{
            jQuery("#shipping\\:city")
            .replaceWith('<input type="text" class=" input-text required-entry absolute-advice " title="City" value="' + shippingCity + '" id="shipping:city" name="shipping[city]" autocomplete="off">');
        }




    }
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        shippingSwitchCityField();
        jQuery('#shipping\\:country_id').change(function() {
            shippingSwitchCityField();
        });
   })
</script>
```

Now you want to leave the rest of the template in place and simply add these to the top.

**Notes on this approach**

I did not want to get into a detailed answer here so I simply copied what the template has done as I think this could be simple for people to work with, but personally I would do the following:

1. Use prototype and not jquery, this is just personal choice as I like prototype....no idea why though,
2. Use tables to store the city information,
3. Link the country, region and city select fields so that when one changes they all change to should the correct information,
4. Move the JavaScript into separate files when possible so that they are not in the template,

*Thanks to magepsycho for the blog as I say I simply copied the code here to get a quick answer*

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I have the same error: "PHP Fatal error:  Class 'MagePsycho_Citydropdown_Helper_Data' not found in /home/site/public_html/prova/app/Mage.php on line 547"

Comment: You have a file called `Data.php` in the path `app/code/local/MagePsycho/Citydropdown/Helper`

Comment: Yes I have this

Comment: And all caches have been cleared?

Comment: Yes but I have compilation active, I restart it and now I haven't error. Thanks so much

Comment: Ah good to know, I always forget compilation mode.

Comment: Why "$helper = Mage::helper('directory'); " instead of returning a normal string array?

Answer (score 1):

Use this for INDIA Cities

```
INSERT INTO directory_country_region VALUES
(NULL , "IN", "Andaman and Nicobar","Andaman and Nicobar"),
(NULL , "IN", "Andhra Pradesh","Andhra Pradesh"),
(NULL , "IN", "Arunachal Pradesh","Arunachal Pradesh"),
(NULL , "IN", "Assam","Assam"),
(NULL , "IN", "Bihar","Bihar"),
(NULL , "IN", "Chandigarh","Chandigarh"),
(NULL , "IN", "Chhattisgarh","Chhattisgarh"),
(NULL , "IN", "Dadra and Nagar Haveli","Dadra and Nagar Haveli"),
(NULL , "IN", "Daman and Diu","Daman and Diu"),
(NULL , "IN", "Delhi","Delhi"),
(NULL , "IN", "Goa","Goa"),
(NULL , "IN", "Gujarat","Gujarat"),
(NULL , "IN", "Haryana","Haryana"),
(NULL , "IN", "Himachal Pradesh","Himachal Pradesh"),
(NULL , "IN", "Jammu and Kashmir","Jammu and Kashmir"),
(NULL , "IN", "Jharkhand","Jharkhand"),
(NULL , "IN", "Karnataka","Karnataka"),
(NULL , "IN", "Kerala","Kerala"),
(NULL , "IN", "Lakshadweep","Lakshadweep"),
(NULL , "IN", "Madhya Pradesh","Madhya Pradesh"),
(NULL , "IN", "Maharashtra","Maharashtra"),
(NULL , "IN", "Manipur","Manipur"),
(NULL , "IN", "Meghalaya","Meghalaya"),
(NULL , "IN", "Mizoram","Mizoram"),
(NULL , "IN", "Nagaland","Nagaland"),
(NULL , "IN", "Orissa","Orissa"),
(NULL , "IN", "Pondicherry","Pondicherry"),
(NULL , "IN", "Punjab","Punjab"),
(NULL , "IN", "Rajasthan","Rajasthan"),
(NULL , "IN", "Sikkim","Sikkim"),
(NULL , "IN", "Tamil Nadu","Tamil Nadu"),
(NULL , "IN", "Tripura","Tripura"),
(NULL , "IN", "Uttar Pradesh","Uttar Pradesh"),
(NULL , "IN", "Uttaranchal","Uttaranchal"),
(NULL , "IN", "West Bengal","West Bengal");



INSERT INTO directory_country_region_name (locale ,region_id ,name )
    SELECT 'en_US', tmp.region_id, tmp.default_name FROM directory_country_region
        AS tmp WHERE tmp.country_id='IN';
```

In your databse

Comment: these are states. tis question is about cities dropdown not about states

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for this for few days. I came up with a solution which suited my need. This is what I did.

**Goto app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml**

Find : `<input type="text" title="<?php echo $this->__('City') ?>" name="billing[city]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getCity()) ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('city') ?>" id="billing:city" />`

and replace it with :

```
<select id="billing:city" name="billing[city]" title="<?php echo $this->__('City') ?>" class="validate-select" style="display:none;">
     <option><?php echo $this->__('Please select city') ?></option>
     <option value="<?php echo $this->__('Mumbai') ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Mumbai') ?></option>
     <option value="<?php echo $this->__('Thane') ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Thane') ?></option>
     <option value="<?php echo $this->__('Navi Mumbai') ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Navi Mumbai') ?></option>
</select>
```

Use the city names you want instead of Mumbai,Thane, Navi Mumbai. It worked for me.

Comment: Does that data was collected in DB without making any other code changes?

Answer (score -1):

One more simple / alternative way to add city dropdown in easy way..!

**Go to "app/Mage.php"** 
we have two functions, you can use whichever suits your requirement.

```
//<!--PRAGS  -->
public static function magento_citystate() {

    $array = array(
        "Maharashtra" => array('Mumbai', 'Thane', 'Navi Mumbai'),
        "Gujrat" => array('Surat', 'Ahamadabad')
    );

    $str = '';

    $i = 0;

    $str.= "<option value=''>-Please select City-</option>";
    foreach ($array as $st => $state) {

        sort($state);
        $str.= "<optgroup label='" . ucfirst($st) . "'>";
        foreach ($state as $ct => $city) {
            $str.="<option value='" . ucfirst($city) . "'>";
            $str.= $city;
            $str.="</option>";
        }
        $str.="</optgroup>";
        $i++;
    }

    return $str;
}
//<!--PRAGS -->
public static function magento_only_city() {
    $array = array(
        "Mumbai",
        "Thane",
        "Navi Mumbai",
        "kolhapur",
        "Surat",
        "Baroda",
        "Ahmedabad",
        "Udaipur",
        "Jaipur",
        "Delhi",
        "faridabad",
        "Noida",
        "Gurgoan",
        "gaziabad",
        "chandigadh",
        "dehradun",
        "lucknow",
        "kanpur",
        "agra",
        "allahbad",
        "kolkata",
        "cuttak",
        "bhubneshwar",
        "vishakapatnam",
        "hydrabad",
        "manglore",
        "banglore",
        "mysore",
        "chennai",
        "madhurai",
        "coimbatore",
        "trivandrum",
        "kochi",
        "indore",
        "bhopal",
        "pune",
        "nagpur",
        "nasik",
        "guwahati",
        "jamshedpur",
        "bilaspur",
        "jabalpur",
        "madgao",
        "panjim",
        "rajkot",
        "jodhpur",
        "amritsar",
        "jalandar",
        "panchkula",
        "mohali",
        "raipur",
        "ranchi",
    );
    $str = '';

     $str.= "<option value=''>-Please select City-</option>";

    sort($array);
    foreach ($array as $ct) {
        $str.="<option value='" . ucfirst($ct) . "'>";
        $str.= ucfirst($ct);
        $str.="</option>";
    }

    return $str;
}
```

**Go to : app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml**

and Replace Text Box with Drop down

```
      <div class="input-box">
                        <!--PRAGS-->

                        <?php 
                        $v = Mage::magento_citystate(); 
                        //$v1 = Mage::magento_only_city(); 
                        ?>
                        <select class="validate-select required-entry" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('City')) ?>" name="billing[city]" id="billing:city">
                           <?php echo $v; ?>
                        </select>


                        <?php /*
                          <input type="text" title="<?php echo    Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('City')) ?>" name="billing[city]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getCity()) ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('city') ?>" id="billing:city" />
                         */ ?>
                     </div>
```

Note : **This will applicable only on Front End, not Admin panel. Only considering India is Country.**

Tested in : **Magento ver. 1.9.2.1**
Hope this will helpful for someone.

Comment: Hacking custom functions into `Mage.php`? Seriously?

Comment: @FabianSchmengler yes, its not a good method. But can you suggest one